# Is there a "Modulus Equals" operator?

Tags: ruby, equals, modulus

```
position = 14
position = position - position%3
=> 12
```

That code above works, but I am loath to reference `position` three times. Is there an equivalent `++` for what I am attempting to do above? I envision something like `position =-%3`.

I can't find anything in the ruby-docs. Anyone?

Comment: position -= position%3, okay down to two.

Comment: Why do you want to narrow this down so much?

Comment: yeah, and great code readability!

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively (just for some variety):

```
position = (position / 3) * 3
```

This assumes `position` holds an integer, not a float (like `14.0`). In which case you could do `(position.to_i / 3) * 3`.